# Using selenium to find values from a dynamic webpage table

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a python code which uses selenium to open a College results web page, input some student values and open the results page of that student.
The results page has a dynamic table whose HTML code I'm not able to access. How do I find values of a specific row and column ?

My python code to open the College results web page is :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
firefox_browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\gecko\geckodriver.exe')
firefox_browser.get("http://results.drait.in/")
time.sleep(5)
print("Opening firefox")
select = Select(firefox_browser.find_element_by_id('ugpg'))
select.select_by_visible_text('UG-SEE')
name_input = firefox_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#usn")
play_button = firefox_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#submit")
name_input.send_keys("1DA17ISxxx")
play_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
print("Done")
```

The above code opens up the main results page which has the subjects the student has enrolled for and the respective grades.

How can I access a particular row and column based on the subject code and exam type and return that value to my python code to print ?

I am not able to find the HTML code of the results page in order to access the table using the table name.

The homepage of the results page looks like this : https://imgur.com/a/1ZgENY6

The result page with the subject details and grades after providing student ID looks like this : https://imgur.com/a/xDAJ7IL

Thanks

Comment: Unaable to access your link , Can you provide working url or DOM?

Comment: Use this : http://results.drait.in Or you can click on the first link here : https://www.dr-ait.org/autonomy/results/

Comment: tried both but getting This site can’t be reached

Comment: can't see the results page that you're talking about without someone's usn

Comment: Choose the option "UG-SEE" under examination, and for USN, you can give 1IDA17ISxxx, xxx can range from 002-045. That should get you to the results page

Comment: Can not access any of results.drait.in or dr-ait.org/autonomy/results. Is it possible for you to share HTML DOM here. In the mean time you can get some common locator for each row in your table, use find_elements by to get list of all rows and loop through all rows to get / perform required value/action. Please share DOM if you are not able to find correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to import selenium webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Then you have to import Keys to enable enter key

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Then if you want to use `time.sleep()` you have to import time module

```
import time
```

Inspect the table you can take xpath of all `<tr>` tags present in the table tag

your xpath will look like this `/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr[1]`

from this remove index values `/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr`

using len method you can see how many rows are the

```
a = len(firefox_browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr"))
```

similarly use xpath of `<th>` tags for columns

your xpath will look like this `/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]`

from this remove index values of `<th>` tag `/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/th`

using len method you can see how many colums are the

```
b = len(firefox_browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/th"))
```

now `a` represents how many rows are there and `b` represents the no of columns

Write a for loop

```
for r in range(2,a+1):#starting from 2 because first rows is headings
   for c in range(1,b+1):
        #use the variables a and b instead of the index of <tr> and <th>
        
         value = 
firefox_browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr["+r+"]/th["+c+"]")
         print(value.text)
```

If you want use if statements to pick elements from particular heading

use like this

```
check=firefox_browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]")

if check.text == "your value":
       #do something
```